# default date in form inputs as first and last day of previous month

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I want to change my inputs and add default date as first and last day of previous month.

For example - when we have some day of December, I want to have inputs date 01.11 and 30.11. But when we have some day of February, I want to have inputs date 01.02 and 28.02 (or 29.02).

My code of form at the moment:

```
<form action="generate.php" method="post">
     First day: <input type="date" name="start_date" value="2018-12-01">
     Last day: <input type="date" name="end_date" value="2018-12-31">
     <button>Generate it!</button>
</form>
```

Do you have any idea? :)

Comment: post something you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer on this question in my opinion  is this code:

```
$startDate = new DateTime("first day of previous month");
$endDate = new DateTime("last day of previous month");
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want the first and last day of the previous month then this should work for you:

```
$curDate=date(Y-m-d);
$month=intval(date(m))-1;
$year=intval(date(Y));
if($month==00){ //case current month januar
    $startDate=($year-1)."-12-01";
    $endDate=($year-1)."-12-31";
}
else{   //differating by month
    $startDate=$year."-".$month."-01";
    if($month==1||$month==3||$month==5||$month==7||$month==8||$month==10)
        $endDate=$year."-".$month."-31";
    else if($month==2)
        $endDate=$year."-2-28";
    else
        $endDate=$year."-".$month."-30";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $minDate = date('01-m-Y');

    $currentDate = date('d-m-Y');
    $maxDate = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($currentDate));


    $calculatedDate = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y"))). " + 10 weekdays"));
?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi! I understand that my variables to input are $minDate and $maxDate, yes? If $maxDate displays last day of this month, that $minDate don't work. But maybe because I am newbie in dates string. I use it as value="<?php echo $maxDate ?>" - it is sure?

Comment: @Kacper i made a preview https://www.tehplayground.com/nVdH7y97jkNe6sIq